# Resize image with ImageMagick and set background color

Tags: imagemagick, extend

I want to resize a 100x200 image to a new 400x400 image with ImageMagick.

So far I have the following command:

```
convert in.png -resize^ 400x400 -compose Copy -gravity center -extent 400x400 out.png
```

Now I want to read the color from the top, left pixel of the in.png and set it as background color of the out.png.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the colour of the pixel ar top-left corner (coordinates: 0,0) like this:

```
convert in.png -colorspace rgb -format "%[pixel:p{0,0}]" info:
```

**Output:**

```
rgb(201,200,206)
```

If you are on OSX/Linux/Unix you can capture that in a variable and use it to set the background like this:

```
c=$(convert in.png -colorspace rgb -format "%[pixel:p{0,0}]" info:)
convert in.png -background "$c" ...
```

So, if we start with this image:

[image]

and do this:

```
c=$(convert in.png -colorspace rgb -format "%[pixel:p{0,0}]" info:)

echo $c           # Check that puppy's colour
rgb(255,0,0)      # Yep, it's red

convert -background "$c" in.png -resize 400x400 -gravity center -extent 400x400 out.png
```

we will get this:

[image]

If you are unfortunate enough to be on Windows, you will have to do some unintelligible stuff with `FOR /F` that you will need to work out for yourself from [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).

Comment: On windows I would definitely recommend powershell for this.

Comment: > unintelligible stuff with FOR /F 

You're not wrong here.

Unintelligible is the kindest way to say what should be conveyed in stronger language.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-background` option to set background color:

```
convert in.png -resize 400x400 -background black -compose Copy -gravity center -extent 400x400 out.png
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't look at the top left pixel for the background color, but sets it to black. Ask-er specifically asked about using top left pixel.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to get the background color of the top left pixel, from the 1st frame of an animated gif

```
convert 'original.gif[0]' -colorspace rgb -crop 1x1+0+0 text:
```